# Populate Excel Range using COM object in php

Tags: php, excel, com

I would like to speed up excel generation on server using range. I know hot to populate 1 cell one by one.
For instance:

```
$ExcelApp = new COM("excel.application") or die("Unable to start MS Excel");
$ExcelWordbook = $ExcelApp->Workbooks->Add();   
$ExcelSheet = $ExcelWordbook->Worksheets(1);
$ExcelSheet->Activate;
$ExcelSheet->Cells(1, 1)->value = "id";
$ExcelSheet->Cells(1, 2)->value = "user";
$ExcelSheet->Cells(1, 3)->value = "pn";
```

But How to make it in one shot using range? Something like this of course is not working.

```
 $ExcelSheet->Range("A1:A3")->value = array("id","user","pn");
```

Any idea? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have you try with phpexcel framework its a excellent framework

Comment: I know about PHP excel but It consumes huge amount of memory when I generate bigger excel. I need to use Windows server now which lower performance thats why COM is better solution.